# boost multiple calls to class method

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, callable

In boost::thread is it possible to call a class method with out making the class callable and implementing the void operator()() as in just call the class method

```
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    boost::thread worker(myclass.myfunc,i,param2);
```

I get an error `<unresolved overloaded function type>`

Actually I would prefer to know the same for zi::thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::thread` doesn't need anything special, it will work exactly as you want (minus syntax errors):

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    boost::thread worker(&myclass::myfunc, myclassPointer, i, param2);
```

From the [boost.thread docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor):

> `template <class F,class A1,class A2,...>`
>   
> `thread(F f,A1 a1,A2 a2,...);`
>
> **Effects:** As if `thread(boost::bind(f, a1, a2, ...))`. Consequently, `f` and each `aN` are copied into internal storage for access by the new thread.

Comment: I think this works only if the myclass::myfunc is static member function. You have to pass the object of the class to invoke the class member function.

Comment: @msh : Right, exactly as you would with boost.bind. Not sure what you're getting at...

Comment: I try to say, you can't use as boost::thread worker(&myclass::myfunc, i, param2), if the myclass::myfunc is not static member function (and this won't compile).

Answer (score 3):

For boost::thread you can use boost::bind to call a class member function.

```
myclass obj;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        boost::thread worker(boost::bind(&myclass::myfunc,&obj,i,param2));
```